# How to write, compile and run C# code sections or scripts

Tags: c#, debugging, compilation, ide, intellisense

I want to generate a C# script editor and runner that will be extremely user friendly. What I need is to allow the user to write simple C# script (no method, class and namespace) and be able to run it and see the results in a console/res window.

This requires of course, to behind the scenes wrap the code section with a method, class, namespace and the needed "using" lines, then compile it and run it.

Also required is to load all assemblies from say "plugins" folder and allow the script to use them as if they are added as references.

Would be great to use VS or VS Code as an IDE. That will give the goodies of intellisense, show compile error while writing the script, running the code line by line etc...

Anyone know of some project that already did this, of a simple way to add this functionality to VS as a plugin or a VS Code Extension?

Comment: LINQPad? https://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: @KevinGosse does linqpad have the plugin functionality listed above? (reading a a bit on their website it looks like the answer is no)

Comment: @Joezer You can add other assemblies to LinqPad and use them.

Comment: I guess you have to generate a .cs file where you dump the user's code in a main method and then call MS build to compile and run it. Why not just C# interactive from command line or LINQPad or a console project's main method?

Comment: @KevinGosse - tx, seems on the spot! wanna post as an answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most use-cases are already covered by [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/).

You can write C# code, debug it, add references, and you have debugging helpers for many scenarios.

Comment: I also need to run it in process on an automation use case. But it definitively is the right direction